# Align two inline-block elements inside table-cell to opposite sides

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I want to left align one div and right align another div inside of a table cell.  I've tried to justify the text but it doesn't seem to be working with my setup. *Looking for a pure css solution.* **Also I also am not able to use floats.**

The demo below will show my current layout.  The logo is irrelevant but it's part of my setup so I'm including it.

"Menu Link" should be aligned left. "Facebook" should aligned right.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="row-height">
  <div class="logo-text col-middle">
    <span>Logo Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-social-outer col-middle text-justify">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">Menu Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yq9nyyg1/

Comment: Can you use bootstrap CSS? If so, do this <div class="social pull-right">

Comment: What if you just modify a bit the markup? It will do your work way easier. You can move either `<div class="menu">` or `<div class="social">` to their own table-cell containers. After that, you would just need to add a `text-align: right;` to the required container.

Comment: I know it's possible to complete it that way but I would like to achieve it within the same table-cell.

Comment: @AntonioHernández it seems as if no one could complete the answer within the same table-cell.  Just wanted to say thanks for your input, had to go with an answer that was the same as your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer after comment concerning IE8 compatibility:

https://jsfiddle.net/f2hy3dvm/3/

I added an additional div inside the second `.col-middle` element (which is a table-cell), wrapping the two already existing elements like this:

```
  <div class="menu-social-outer col-middle text-justify">
    <div class="extra1">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">Menu Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#">Facebook</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This new element, `extra1` is a (nested) table, completely filling its container (width: 100%`). I made its children table-cells and aligned the text in the second cell to the right side:

```
.extra1 {
  display: table;
  background: #fa0;
  width: 100%;
}
.extra1 > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.extra1 .social {
  text-align: right;
 }
```

Comment: Would like to retain IE8+ compatibility.

Comment: can you also change the HTML (i.e. add something) or only the CSS?

Comment: Yes I can change the html layout and css if needed.

Comment: please note my completely new answer

Answer (score 0):

This is possible although the method does have a minor side effect.

You can use a pseudo-element to force the text to justify like so.

```css
.container {
  /*for demo only */
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 80%;
}
.logo-text {
  width: 100px;
}
.menu,
.social {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu a {
  color: red;
}
.social a {
  color: green;
}
.row-height {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.col-middle {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu-social-outer {
  background: pink;
}
.menu-social-outer::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-height">
      <div class="logo-text col-middle">
        <span>Logo Text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-social-outer col-middle text-justify">
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">Menu Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="social">
          <a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this pseudo-element creates a link break which increases the height of the div. *I haven't found a work-around for this yet.*

Alternatively, don't use CSS Tables....use Flexbox.

```css
.container {
  /*for demo only */
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 80%;
}
.logo-text {
  width: 100px;
}
.menu,
.social {} .menu a {
  color: red;
}
.social a {
  color: green;
}
.row-height {
  display: flex;
}
.col-middle {} .menu-social-outer {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-height">
      <div class="logo-text col-middle">
        <span>Logo Text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-social-outer col-middle text-justify">
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">Menu Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="social">
          <a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can find a solid solution to the break created by the psuedo that would be ideal.  Would like to retain IE8+ compatibility so flex won't work, although I do know that's definitely the easiest route.